# How to find out if a HTML Element is behind another HTML Element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML :

**HTML :**

```
<div class="stave-container">
  <section id="Captcha"></section>
  <div id="horiz_container_outer">
     <img class="img1" />
       ...
     <img class="imgn"/>
  </div>
</div>

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+         +                            +
+#Captcha +  img | img | img | img     +
+         +  div#horiz_container_outer +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

The section **#Captcha** is fixed!

The div **#horiz_container_outer** is scrollable and contains img element!

How can i detect when a img element are behind the Div #Captcha while
scrolling?

Comment: What? My apologies, but I have no idea what it is you want to do. Or what effort you've put into solving your problem. Or what's going wrong with your current implementation.

Comment: I added some Infos! hope you understand my problem!

Comment: Why you just don't make that DIV transparent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My Solution :**

I put it into the jquery : [.scroll](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) function

```
    $("#horiz_container_outer > img").each(function(){
      if( $("#Captcha").offset().left > $(this).offset().left )
        {
          console.log($(this).attr("class"));
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are attempting to have a section of the screen that doesn't scroll (which is what it sounds like, but I am not quite sure from your question) the standards compliant way to do this is:

```
.non-scroll-div {
  position:fixed;
}
```

Keep compatability in mind however: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-fixed

Answer (score 0):

To copy all the elements from one div to another you could do something like this:

html

```
<div id="fixedDiv"></div>
<div id="stuff"><span>some stuff</span><br /><hr /></div>
```

js

```
document.getElementById("fixedDiv").innerHTML = document.getElementById("stuff").innerHTML;
```

Comment: How can i set a trigger to know when an Img is under my fixed DIV?

Comment: There is no simple way to detect when one element passes under another due to layout or scrolling. Such a thing would be extremely complicated for the browser, because it would have to check all elements against all other elements and fire many many events.